# CSRF With Ajax Polling

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have some AJAX that polls the server every 5 seconds:

```
var date = $('article').first().find('time').text();
console.log(date);

setInterval(function() {
    $.post('pollNewEntries', {'date':date}, newEntrySuccess)
}, 5000);
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a 403 error every time the AJAX tries to poll the server, stating that I have made an invalid CSRF request. I've used AJAX with forms before and included the CSRF token within the forms, but I"m not sure how I would do it with a formless AJAX request like above.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Why are you using a POST for this? A GET is more suitable for an action that just pulls from a db, and would not require CSRF.

Comment: Because I need to pass in the date of the most recent article on the page. Could GET do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is described in the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Add this code to the top of your js:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `csrf` token along with your post data:

```
var date = $('article').first().find('time').text();
console.log(date);

setInterval(function() {
    $.post('pollNewEntries', {'date':date, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'}, newEntrySuccess)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Would this work even though it's not in an HTML template (it's a js file)?

Comment: Oh i thought its a template. But you can do one thing to trick is to have it in `<script>` tag place it in `js.html` and then include `js.html` in sub template `{% include "js.html" %}`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add these lines in your script. Here is an example in coffeescript :

```
### CSRF methods ###
csrfSafeMethod = (method) ->
  # these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
  return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method))

$.ajaxSetup(
  crossDomain: false
  beforeSend: (xhr, settings) ->
    if !csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'))
)
```

Read the documentation : [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

In other hand, as `user1427661` suggests to you, it will be better to use HTTP GET method instead of POST, because you only need to read data and don't write anything. See the [W3 docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).